# How to convert KML to GeoJSON using GeoTools in Java (GeoServer don't accept the result of my conversion)

Tags: java, geojson, kml, geoserver, geotools

I have a KML File and I need convert to GeoJSON.
I am using Geotools in Java for convert KML because GeoServer has problems to import KML. I can convert the files but GeoServer don't accept GeoJSON converted.
When I import GeoJSON converted online, there are no problems.

**Code in Java**

I used this code [Convert Kml with multiple features to Geojson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33386467/convert-kml-with-multiple-features-to-geojson)

```
        FileInputStream reader = new FileInputStream(fileTmp.getAbsolutePath());
        PullParser parser = new PullParser(new KMLConfiguration(), reader, SimpleFeature.class);

        FeatureJSON featureJSON = new FeatureJSON();
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(filename + ".geojson");
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
        ArrayList<SimpleFeature> features = new ArrayList<>();
        SimpleFeature simpleFeature = (SimpleFeature) parser.parse();
        while (simpleFeature != null) {
            LOG.info(simpleFeature);
            features.add(simpleFeature);
            simpleFeature = (SimpleFeature) parser.parse();
        }

        SimpleFeatureCollection featureCollectionUnreprojected = DataUtilities.collection(features);
        
        featureJSON.writeFeatureCollection(featureCollectionUnreprojected, writer);
```

**KML File**

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>KML-Example</name>
    <gx:CascadingStyle kml:id="__managed_style_1BBDE4D1D5209F676816">
        <Style>
            <IconStyle>
                <Icon>
                    <href>https://earth.google.com/earth/rpc/cc/icon?color=1976d2&amp;id=2000&amp;scale=4</href>
                </Icon>
                <hotSpot x="64" y="128" xunits="pixels" yunits="insetPixels"/>
            </IconStyle>
            <LabelStyle>
            </LabelStyle>
            <LineStyle>
                <color>ff2f2fd3</color>
                <width>4</width>
            </LineStyle>
            <PolyStyle>
                <color>402f2fd3</color>
            </PolyStyle>
            <BalloonStyle>
                <displayMode>hide</displayMode>
            </BalloonStyle>
        </Style>
    </gx:CascadingStyle>
    <gx:CascadingStyle kml:id="__managed_style_2EA205CEFB209F676816">
        <Style>
            <IconStyle>
                <scale>1.2</scale>
                <Icon>
                    <href>https://earth.google.com/earth/rpc/cc/icon?color=1976d2&amp;id=2000&amp;scale=4</href>
                </Icon>
                <hotSpot x="64" y="128" xunits="pixels" yunits="insetPixels"/>
            </IconStyle>
            <LabelStyle>
            </LabelStyle>
            <LineStyle>
                <color>ff2f2fd3</color>
                <width>6</width>
            </LineStyle>
            <PolyStyle>
                <color>402f2fd3</color>
            </PolyStyle>
            <BalloonStyle>
                <displayMode>hide</displayMode>
            </BalloonStyle>
        </Style>
    </gx:CascadingStyle>
    <StyleMap id="__managed_style_06849BAC89209F676816">
        <Pair>
            <key>normal</key>
            <styleUrl>#__managed_style_1BBDE4D1D5209F676816</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
        <Pair>
            <key>highlight</key>
            <styleUrl>#__managed_style_2EA205CEFB209F676816</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Placemark id="0C1FAD446F209F671F2B">
        <name>Teste</name>
        <LookAt>
            <longitude>-8.071672824072024</longitude>
            <latitude>40.94572565095269</latitude>
            <altitude>554.9936597887551</altitude>
            <heading>0</heading>
            <tilt>0</tilt>
            <gx:fovy>35</gx:fovy>
            <range>469307.9708133639</range>
            <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
        </LookAt>
        <styleUrl>#__managed_style_06849BAC89209F676816</styleUrl>
        <Polygon>
            <outerBoundaryIs>
                <LinearRing>
                    <coordinates>
                        -80.32039884287052,25.79595095231043,-440.4448477037203 -40.16540389678969,-7.859693178090486,-3537.052188699258 -7.711086121502985,41.24065720616411,-5036.3287754869 -80.32039884287052,25.79595095231043,-440.4448477037203 
                    </coordinates>
                </LinearRing>
            </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

**Expected**

```
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "id":"0C1FAD446F209F671F2B",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Polygon",
            "coordinates":[
               [
                  [
                     -80.32039884287052,
                     25.79595095231043,
                     -440.4448477037203
                  ],
                  [
                     -40.16540389678969,
                     -7.859693178090486,
                     -3537.052188699258
                  ],
                  [
                     -7.711086121502985,
                     41.24065720616411,
                     -5036.3287754869
                  ],
                  [
                     -80.32039884287052,
                     25.79595095231043,
                     -440.4448477037203
                  ]
               ]
            ]
         },
         "properties":{
            "name":"Teste"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

**My result**

```
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Polygon",
            "coordinates":[
               [
                  [
                     -80.3204,
                     25.796,
                     -440.4448
                  ],
                  [
                     -40.1654,
                     -7.8597,
                     -3537.0522
                  ],
                  [
                     -7.7111,
                     41.2407,
                     -5036.3288
                  ],
                  [
                     -80.3204,
                     25.796,
                     -440.4448
                  ]
               ]
            ]
         },
         "properties":{
            "name":"Teste",
            "visibility":true,
            "open":true,
            "LookAt":{
               "type":"Point",
               "coordinates":[
                  -8.0717,
                  40.9457,
                  554.9937
               ]
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{
            "name":"KML-Example",
            "visibility":true,
            "open":true
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: why doesn't GeoServer accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Things have moved on since that last answer, the prefered way to do this is using `DataStore`s:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, XMLStreamException, SAXException {

    KMLDataStore ds = new KMLDataStore(new File(args[0]));
    SimpleFeatureCollection fc = ds.getFeatureSource(ds.getTypeNames()[0]).getFeatures();
    System.out.println("read in " + fc.size() + " features");
    FileDataStore dsx = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(new File("/tmp/test.geojson"));
    dsx.createSchema(fc.getSchema());
    SimpleFeatureStore source = (SimpleFeatureStore) dsx.getFeatureSource(dsx.getTypeNames()[0]);
    source.addFeatures(fc);

  }
```

However the KMLDatastore only reads in one feature before
hitting the end of the stream. I can't check if your KML is valid as all the KML validators have gone.

Your problem is that the `KMLDataStore` is unsupported so while you can raise an issue against it there is no saying when it would be fixed.

Comment: Can you tell me which maven dependency contains the KMLDataStore class?

Comment: https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/data/kml.html - it's an unsupported plugin so you will need to build it yourself